# AMQP 1.0 and distributed transactions

Tags: amqp, distributed-transactions, azureservicebus, qpid

Question 1
A topic that is bothering me for a long time. I'm working with (QPID) AMQP 1.0 and trying to enable distributed transactions. Did anyone managed to do so? 1.0 spec (http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/) points out that amqp:distributed-transactions capability will be described in Part 6 however it is not written yet.

Has anyone successfully managed to use distributed transactions using AMQP 1.0?

Question 2 
Does QPID AMQP 1.0 client support distributed transactions?

Question 3 
Does Microsoft Azure Service Bus support distributed transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you are correct in that the specification for AMQP 1.0 distributed transactions is not complete and consequently there is no support for distributed transactions over AMQP 1.0 in Apache Qpid or Azure Service Bus.

Regards,

Dave.

(Service Bus team)